# Accessing Gateway Properties from another microservice using Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

I have **Config Microservice , Employee Microservice , Gateway Microservice** . application.yml will be loaded from Config Microservices for Employee and Gateway Microservice using the **Spring.cloud.config**.

i need to use one of the Gateway Property in the Employee Microservice . how to achieve this ?

Config Microservice contains below files

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 8080
```

**Gateway.yml**

```
app:
 access-table: true
```

**Employee.yml**

```
 server:
  port: 8081
```

In the Employee Microservice, Employee.yml is loaded using the Spring cloud config URI .

```
 cloud:
   config:
     uri: http://localhost:8080
```

how can i access the **access-table** property from the **gateway.yml** in the Employee Microservices ?

i tired using name property but it overrides the other configs , i need to access only that property . is there a way?

```
cloud:
 config:
  uri: http://localhost:8080
  name: Employee.yml,Gateway.yml
```

Comment: Employee service is running on the same gateway service, right ?

Comment: Both are separate Spring boot Application.

Comment: if both are separate spring boot application , then i would suggest that you should expose gateway related property through a GET api . which can be used by employee service. or use common service to load common properties and add them through packaging of gradle or maven.

Comment: can be .. but is this is good way of doing this?

Comment: yes because owner service in your case gateway service would have responsibility of managing that property . and however wants to use it can access it using API.

Comment: In addition to that you can provide access control using oauth to restrict other service using this api .

Comment: Thanks let me try with different option if nothing works then i use this .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have any common properties that required in multiple micro-services then place those properties in config server `application.yml`.
This `application.yml` for all micro-services even if have any profile.

Comment: i added property to config server application.yml but it couldnt reslove the property . should we add anythin in the config server

Comment: Could not resolve placeholder 'app.access-table' in value "${app.access-table}". but how does the other Spring Boot app know to pick from the config server application.yml ? Did u tried this  before ?